# To find addition formula for tan(x) by analytic methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question is to clarify an answer to a previous question. Please do not delete as duplicate.

Here is the question:

Assume that we only know $\tan(0)=0$ and also given the relation $\tan'(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x)$

How can I get the additon formula
$\tan(x+h)=\tan(x)+\tan(h) / (1−\tan(x)\tan(h))$

...... and analytic methods ? (without using geometry)

The answer by achille hui

Let $ϕ(x,h)$ be the addition formula for $tan(x+h)$ $\tan(x+h)=\tan(x)+\tan(h)/(1−\tan(x)\tan(h))$ { ie. we know the answer, now we prove it}

ϕ satisfies the same ODE $d/dx y(x)=1+y(x)^2$

Since $ϕ(x,h) = \tan(x+h)$ at $x=0$ you can use the fundamental theorem of ODE (in particular, the uniqueness part of solution to an ODE ) to conclude $\tan(x+h) = ϕ(x,h)$

I need someone to fill in the details of the answer. Assume minimal knowlede of calculus, I have forgotten Maclaurins series and never knew Moebius transform.

Comment: Do you want a proof assuming one already has the formula, or do you also want a way to find the formula? If the latter, how much may one assume about the shape of the formula?